About information and algorithm improvement
I encountered a problem recently, the original problem is as below:
A facility has $a$ identical rooms, each room has $b$ distinguishable teleporters. Only one fixed correct teleporter in each room leads to the next room, while others will lead to the first room. The correct teleporter in the last room leads to escape. Now you are in the first room, find an algorithm that guarantees escape in finite steps.
My solution: Label all possible correct teleporter sequences as $S_1,S_2,...,S_{b^a}$. For each $1\leq i\leq b^a$, we assume that $S_{i}$ is the correct sequence. Then for each $1\leq j\leq a$,  we assume we were on the $j$-th room when we started to assume that $S_{i}$ is the correct sequence, and then we try an escaping route asserted by the assumptions above.
This algorithm has a time complexity of $O(a^3b^a)$: For each of the $a$ operations assuming being on a certain room at the start, we need to calculate $O(a^2)$ states to find the current state.
I understand that the time complexity cannot be lower than $O(ab^a)$ since that is the number of states to go through to explore all sequences. In fact, if the rooms were explicitly labelled, the complexity would be $O(b^a)$.
My questions here:

Is there any information theory stuff that gives an exact lower bound on the time complexity of the solution of this problem?

Find an algorithm that satisfies that bound.


